# How to use DynamicLinq "contains” or “like” with numbers?

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

Tried this:

```
.Where("MyColumnID.Contains(@0)", myArray)
```

But what i got was:

> No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Int32'

Any other ways? Something like *SqlMethods.Like*, but in DynamicLinq?

Comment: what type and value of `myArray`?

Comment: possible duplicate [How to Type Cast dynamically to string while using Contains in Dynamic LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315762/how-to-type-cast-dynamically-to-string-while-using-contains-in-dynamic-linq])

Answer (score 3):

The `Contains()` operator works the other way around: It's the array which contains the number, thus it should read as follows:

```
"@0.Contains(MyColumnID)"
```

I am however, not sure if this is even possible within DynamicLinq. This other SO question deals with the same problem:

[Query data using "Contains" keyword in Dynamic Linq in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633066/query-data-using-contains-keyword-in-dynamic-linq-in-c-sharp)

It suggests the following should work:

```
int[] CandidateIdsArray = new int[]{4, 78, 101}
var dynamicLinqQuery = 
    Candidates.Where("@0.Contains(CandidateId)", CandidateIdsArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.Where("@0.Contains(MyColumnID)", myArray)
```